# How to remove padding in Navigation Icon Menu

Tags: android, toolbar, android-appbarlayout, android-jetpack-navigation

Am using Navigation Component Jetpack, so i have some button automatically generate in my toolbar. Like so:
[image: pic1]

But the result is so disappointing, that `AppcompatImageButton` which represent Burgerbutton take too large padding, like this:
[image: pic2]

I have tried something like this but, it doesn't give any effect

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
            app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="5">
</LinearLayout>

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

How can i reduce that padding size?

Comment: That looks like the minimum accessible touch size of 48x48dp already.

Comment: do you mean i can't reduce that padding anymore?

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is make a separate layout for toolbar and add a image of Burgerbutton there and set the desire padding or margin to it.

```
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:background="@color/appWhiteColor"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btnBurger"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:background="@drawable/nav_icon"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_2sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_13sdp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_8sdp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guidelinev2">
            </ImageView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:text="Orders"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                android:fontFamily="@font/comfortaa_regular"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guidelinev2"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">
            </TextView>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/guidelinev1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.6"/>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/guidelinev3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.85"/>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/guidelinev2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.1"/>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/guidelineh1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.15"/>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

now put this in your navigationDrawerActivity

```
      ImageView expand = findViewById(R.id.btnBurger);
      expand.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
    });
```

Comment: actually i need that `AppCompatImageButton` in order to use their animation when transition between fragments in NavigationComponent. If i changed it, i might lose it